# How do "Lost Places" work?

Tags: neptunia-v

My Scouts have found weird non-dungeon "places" on some of the maps. I'm told these are called "Lost Places". I have found several in my travels but still have no idea what they do or how exactly you get them.

- What do they do? Just give me items when found?
- How do I find them? Just scouting any random place?
- I'm told distrusting Lost Place info changes which Lost Place is unlocked. How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lost Places are locations that can be found by Scouts, and only by scouting. Discovering a Lost Place nets you 1-2 of an Idea Chip and 1-2 of an Item, which is specific to each possible Lost Place. It also shows up on your map with its name, although after its discovery you have no real meaningful interaction you can do with it anymore.

Each region of the overworld (so, each nation plus Hello Island and PC Island) has 6 possible Lost Places that can be found. You can find a Lost Place by having scouts search in any dungeon in that region. However, in any given playthrough, only 3 Lost Places can be found per region.

This is where the Trust system comes into play, which plays differently than it does for every other usage of the system.

- If you trust the report of a Scout, then the Scout's information about the location of a Lost Place will be correct, and you will get that.
- If you distrust the report of a Scout, then the Scout will report about a *different* Lost Place, and while it will note that the Scout was wrong about where it was, you do actually find this different Lost Place.

So even though there are six Lost Places per region, there's only 3 possible locations for each Lost Place, as two Lost Places occupy each such location. If this is confusing, picture it as if each region has 3 cards - you can either find a card face up (trusted) or face down (distrusted), and that determines which you get. Your usage of the trust system is generally to specify which Idea Chips you want - so if for example you get a particularly meh chip from a specific Lost Place, reloading and seeing what the opposite side has can be handy.

Comment: For reference, best I can tell, "distrust" and "trust" are separate lists of Lost Places, so if you always trust you'll get one set of Lost Places and if you always Distrust it seems you'll always get the remaining set of places

Comment: Since I haven't written down all the names/prizes from this run (though maybe I might do that later), let's picture it like so - let's say Planeptune has 6 Lost Places: A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2. When a Scout reports about a Lost Place, it picks a random letter that hasn't been revealed yet, corresponding to some position on the map. Your choice of trust/distrust only affects the number. So if you always trust or always distrust, you'll always get the same set of results regardless of which order they are found. Knowing more specific only relates to narrower choicemaking.